# META-INF folder in Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, struts2

I did a project in Struts 2 in Google App Engine with Java Persistence API. persistence.xml file should be in META-INF folder. Where can I find the META-INF folder? Where should I save the persistence.xml file. Im using Eclipse as my development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

META-INF folder should be located under MyProject/src directory, for example:

```
MyProject/
  src/
    META-INF/
      jdoconfig.xml
    log4j.properties
    logging.properties
  war/
    WEB-INF/
      lib/
        ...App Engine JARs...
      appengine-web.xml
      web.xml
    index.html
```